# how to save complex grep output in gvim

Tags: vim, grep

In my gvim file I have something like  below

```
Before line
name1/name2/name3/
next line
```

name2/name3 is the pattern of my interest.

I want to delete the line containing the pattern and the next line of matched pattern.

I want to save the both lines in other file. I am able to search and delete the lines using global

```
:g/name2\/name3/,+1d
```

but not able to redirect it into other file.

How can I save the grep output to some other file.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `write >> f` to append to the file `f` (or `write! >> f` if you want to create `f` if it doesn't exist).

```
:g/name2\/name3/,+ write! >> f | ,+d
```

---

Alternatively you could use `:redir >>` (which avoids repeating the `,+` range) :

```
:g/name2\/name3/,+1d | redir! >> f | silent echon @" | redir END
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better solution, but after you deleted the lines they are in the `"` register (you can check with `:reg`).

Just open a new buffer with `:new`, paste the register with `p` and save the file with `:w myfilename`